# WCF Catastrophic Failure

Tags: wcf, crash

I've got a real lemon on my hands. I hope someone who has the same problem or know how to fix it could point me in the right direction.

**The Setup**

I'm trying to create a WCF data service that uses an ADO Entity Framework model to retrieve data from the DB. I've added the WCF service reference and all seems fine. I have two sets of data service calls. The first one retrieves a list of all "users" and returns (this list does not include any dependent data (eg. address, contact, etc.). The second call is when a "user" is selected, the application request to include a few more dependent information such as address, contact details, messages, etc. given a user id. This also seems to work fine.

**The Lemon**

After some user selection change, ie. calling for more dependent data from the data service, the application stops to respond.

> Crash error:
>
> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9989999. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I restart the debugging process but the application will not make any data service calls until after about a minute or so, VS 08 displays a message box with error:

> Unable to process request from service. 'http://localhost:61768/ConsoleService.svc'. Catastrophic failure.

I've Googled the hell out of this error and related issues but found nothing of use.

**Possible Solutions**

I've found some leads as to the source of the problem. In  the client's app.config:

1. maxReceivedMessageSize > Set to a higher value, eg. 5242880.
2. receiveTimeout > Set to a higher value, eg. 00:30:00

I've tried these but all in vain. I suspect there is an underlying problem that cannot be fixed by simply changing some numbers. Any leads would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved it =P.

**Cause**

The WCF service works fine. It was the data service calls that was the culprit. Every time I made the call, I instantiated a new reference to the data service, but never closed/disposed the service reference. So after a couple of calls, the data service reaches its maximum connection and halts.

**Solution**

Make sure to close/dispose of any data service reference properly. Best practice would be to enclose in a using statement.

```
using(var dataService = new ServiceNS.ServiceClient() )
{
    // Use service here        
}
// The service will be disposed and connection freed.
```

Comment: Does the singleton pattern with client as property and using async service reference creates the issues???

Answer (score 4):

Glad to see you fixed your problem.

However, you need to be carefull about using the using statement. Have a look at this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx